# Facebook requests example project

Tags: ios, xcode, facebook

Has anyone found an example project for this tutorial on facebook requests: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/send-requests-using-ios-sdk/

Since I have already integrated a list of facebook friends a user has, can I send each a message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the actual project on GitHub, https://github.com/fbsamples/ios-3.1-howtos/tree/master/SendRequestsHowTo

If you already have a list of Facebook friends you can just send them a message. Just get a comma-separated, string representation of those friends, and pass the info to the "suggested" parameter:

```
NSString *friendList = @"12345, 4567";
NSMutableDictionary* params = 
    [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
    @"Check this out.",  @"message",
    friendList, @"suggestions",
    nil];

[self.facebook dialog:@"apprequests"
            andParams:params
          andDelegate:self];
```

Comment: but in the code you provided me, Im i sending a request like in the sample code, or a private message? which is better?

Comment: It's not a private message. It will be sent as a notification, which is also private in the sense that it's a one-to-one communication. Sending as a notification is useful if you want to handle the fact that the user clicked on the notification in your app. One scenario may be the user is sending a gift to their friends. If you send a message, then the friend who gets the message could reply, and now the communication would be via Facebook Messenger, outside the control of your app. If that's okay you can try that.